# Trigger class with pure javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I found fastest pure javascript trigger [link](http://jsperf.com/javascript-toggle-performance/3).
I don't know why is not working for me.

```
<a href="#" id="open">Open</a>

var ele = document.getElementById('open');
ele.onclick = function() { ele.className == '' ? 'hide' : ''; };
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `ele.className = ele.className == '' ? 'hide' : '';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a test but not assigning the returned value. I think you should change this

```
ele.onclick = function() { ele.className == '' ? 'hide' : ''; };
```

to this

```
ele.onclick = function() { ele.className = (ele.className == '' ? 'hide' : ''); };
```